# How to CreateJsonString from appsettings section

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, box-api, boxapiv2

I previously stored my box json config as a separate file which I would store outside of my application and get the location of it and pull the config and ReadToEnd. However I want due to the stress of managing folder permissions and what not for IIS, I prefer to just store the json config inside my appsettings.json. However, I am not sure how I actually can convert the json structure of that section into my code. My code so far is as follows:

```
this.token = token;
var config = BoxConfigBuilder.CreateFromJsonString(configuration.GetSection("Box:ProductionConfig").ToString()).Build();
_session = new BoxJWTAuth(config);
```

However when running this is draws the folloing netwonsoft error:

> "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: M. Path '', line 0, position 0."

I am thinking that I need to convert the appsetting configure section to a json string but not sure how to do that.

My appsettings.json is as follows:

```
 {"Box": {
"ProductionConfig": {
  "boxAppSettings": {
    "clientID": “dsafafdsafasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfsdaf”,
    "clientSecret": “dfasdfasdfasdfasdfdsfdfedfdf”,
    "appAuth": {
      "publicKeyID": "kdjfkalsfjakslf;a",
      "privateKey": "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\nkdsajfl;sajdkfl;asjdkfl;sajdkfl;asjkdfl;asjdkfl;asjfklas;djfkdasld;fjklsa;fjskal;f\n——END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "passphrase": “dasfsafsadfasdfasdfasdfsa”
    }
  },
  "enterpriseID": "dsafasfdsafasdf"
},
"ProductionDomain": "https://testing.app.box.com"},}
```

My previous code I used would read the file as follows except ProductionConfig was actually a path to the json file:

```
        this.token = token;
        var boxProductionConfigLocation = Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(env.ContentRootPath).ToString(), configuration["Box:ProductionConfig"]);
        var config = BoxConfigBuilder.CreateFromJsonString(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(boxProductionConfigLocation)).Build();
        _session = new BoxJWTAuth(config);
```

Comment: Please share your appsettings.json too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from `configuration.GetSection("Box:ProductionConfig").ToString()`. ToString will not fetch the string, instead use,

```
configuration.GetValue<string>("Box:ProductionConfig")
```

Alernaively you can ry,

```
configuration.GetSection("Box:ProductionConfig")                                                 .Get<string>()
```

Update:
With the updated appsetings I see that is just a normal config and not a json string so it cannot be read directly. You will have to create a backing class with public properties and then convert it back to json.

```
//First create these classes
public class ProductionConfig
{
    public BoxAppSettings BoxAppSettings { get; set; }
    public string EnterpriseID { get; set; }
}

public class BoxAppSettings
{
    public string ClientID { get; set; }
    public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
    public AppAuth AppAuth { get; set; }
}

public class AppAuth
{
    public string PublicKeyID { get; set; }
    public string PrivateKey { get; set; }
    public string Passphrase { get; set; }
}

//then read it like this
this.token = token;
var configJson= JsonSerializer.Serialize(configuration.GetSection("Box:ProductionConfig").Get<ProductionConfig>());
var config = BoxConfigBuilder.CreateFromJsonString(configJson).Build();
_session = new BoxJWTAuth(config);
```

Config binding is reflection based and hence it cant bind dynamically to JsonElement.

Comment: Using this method creates the "System.ArgumentNullException has been thrown"

Comment: Is hard to tell without seeing the actual appsettings, but I have another suggestion in the answer

Comment: Just added the appsettings above.

Comment: Added the answer, you can read it as `JsonElement`

Comment: Any reason the .Get{JsonElement} is drawing a error saying "CS0119: 'ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>(IConfiguration)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context". Is there a package i need to add or something?

Comment: Which version of dotnet are you using?

Comment: I am using .net 6. Hoping to upgrade project to .net 8 eventually but havent had time.

Comment: uopdated the answer to include backing class.

Comment: Ha I know this is painstaking but I appreciate your help. I feel like it shouldnt have been this difficult and I actually was starting to move towards this route like you. However, you code draws an error on the last line: "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Box.V2.Config.BoxConfigBuilder' to 'Box.V2.Config.IBoxConfig'". Any thoughts?

Comment: Just add .Build() to the config line and its good!